# How do I transpose data in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to transpose data using sql in Google BigQuery SQL? I could not figure out how to use PIVOT as it needs an aggregate function.

Also, can you share how to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE if the dates are not known?

here is the table data:

```
date, timestamp_30seconds, profit_loss_pct
2023-09-05, 14:46:30, -0.05
2023-09-06, 14:46:30, -0.06
2023-09-07, 14:46:30, -0.04
2023-09-05, 14:47:00, -0.05
2023-09-06, 14:47:00, -0.04
2023-09-07, 14:47:00, -0.06
```

Desired output

```
timestamp, 2023-09-05, 2023-09-06, 2023-09-07
14:46:30, -0.05, -0.06, -0.04
14:47:00, -0.05, -0.04, -0.06
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to go about it:

```
SELECT
  timestamp_30seconds AS timestamp,
  MAX(CASE WHEN date = '2023-09-05' THEN profit_loss_pct END) AS "2023-09-05",
  MAX(CASE WHEN date = '2023-09-06' THEN profit_loss_pct END) AS "2023-09-06",
  MAX(CASE WHEN date = '2023-09-07' THEN profit_loss_pct END) AS "2023-09-07"
FROM
  your_table_name
GROUP BY
  timestamp_30seconds
ORDER BY
  timestamp_30seconds;
```

You may use conditional aggregation to pivot the data in Google BigQuery SQL such that it produces the required results. To conditionally aggregate the profit_loss_pct based on the timestamp_30seconds and date, we will utilize CASE statements.

Comment: Thanks, Nayem. What if the dates are not known, can it be dynamic?